# How to get data using SQL Join

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have two tables:

demo_tbl

```
 name | banch| gender  | add_by |
================================
name1 |   ME |  Male   | admin1 |
name2 |  CSE |  Female | admin1 |    
name3 |   ME |  Male   | admin2 |
name4 |   CSE|  Male   | admin3 |
```

status_tbl

```
name   | status |
=================
name1  |    1   | 
name3  |    1   |
```

I want to join these two table and the output should be as follows.

```
name  | status | Gender |
=========================
name1 |    1   |  Male  |
name2 |        |  Female|
name3 |    1   |  Male  |
```

But I am unable to get this output with following query.

```
SELECT demo_tbl.name, demo_tbl.gender, status_tbl.status
FROM demo_tbl LEFT JOIN status_tbl ON demo_tbl.name=status_tbl.name 
AND demo_tbl.add_by = 'admin1' AND status_tbl.status = '1'
```

Please anyone tell me what is wrong with my query.?

Comment: `@Md. Suman Kabir`  It shows `name4` also. How should I avoid this.

Comment: `demo_tbl.add_by = 'admin1'  AND status_tbl.status = '1'` is not working properly in query. So is there any alternative way to do this. ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, the query should be this :

```
SELECT demo_tbl.name, demo_tbl.gender, status_tbl.status
FROM demo_tbl 
LEFT JOIN status_tbl 
ON demo_tbl.name=status_tbl.name AND status_tbl.status = '1'
where demo_tbl.add_by in('admin1', 'admin2')
```

Perhaps you were getting output only for `name1` and `name2` because you have this condition `demo_tbl.add_by = 'admin1'` which is valid only for `name1` and `name2`

Comment: `@Md. Suman Kabir` You are right, but as per the condition `demo_tbl.add_by = 'admin1'` it should get only admin1 rows from `demo_tbl` and `status_tbl.status = '1'` should get only row which has `status=1`, At the end `name4` should not be displayed in output as per the condition applied in query.

Comment: As you are using `LEFT JOIN`, the joined table `status_tbl` does not filter records, may be you are looking for `INNER JOIN` But the query i provided above will definitely give you the expected result you told in the question.